# Why the Ack number is bigger than the last Seq number?

Tags: tcp, networking

Why the Ack number is bigger than the last Seq number?

[image]

you see the Ack response for each two TCP packages.

but there I have a question, you see the Ack response for `Seq=19997`, `Seq=22893` and `Seq=25789`.

but the 3 Ack are not by add 1. （ `Seq:19997`->`Ack:21445`, `Seq:22893`->`Ack:24341`, `Seq:25789`->`Ack:27237`）.

Comment: "_Segments also carry an acknowledgment number which is the sequence number of the **next expected data octet** of transmissions in the reverse direction._"

Comment: ACK = ISN + all received data + 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ACK` is always bigger than the last `SEQ` number because `ACK` is the next expected value.

Let's assume I received a packet which has a sequence number zero `(SEQ=0)` and let's say that the size of the packet is `k` bytes. Then my ack will be the last sequence number `(0)+(k)+1`